# How can I pull after git --skip-worktree?

Tags: git

My workflow:

run `git update-index --skip-worktree example.txt`

modify `example.txt`

run `pull` "origin"

I got:
`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: example.txt`

So, I think `--skip-worktree` is useless

Comment: `--skip-worktree` is not useless because it warns you and prevent to lost your changes. That's just that your file is not intended to be updated in the repository (or very rarely, so you have to merge it so often by doing `--no-skip-worktree` before)

Comment: If you're using `--skip-worktree` to ignore changes to tracked files, the [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile) specifically says not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel `--skip-worktree` on `example.txt`.

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree example.txt
```

Stash the changes.

```
git stash
```

Pull from the remote.

```
git pull origin
```

Apply the stashed changes.

```
git stash pop
# or
git stash apply
```

Solve the conflicts if any.

Cast `--skip-worktree` on `example.txt` again.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree example.txt
```

The error protects your modified version from being overwritten by the fetched version.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and wondered 'what is the point of --skip-worktree then?'

There is a good explanation here:
https://www.baeldung.com/git-assume-unchanged-skip-worktree

git update-index --skip-worktree 'is useful when we want to add local changes to a file without pushing them to the upstream'.

But as others have pointed out above, your local changes are prevented from being overwritten by a pull.